# div with 100% height on any device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´ve been trying this for a long time and I can´t find a solution.

I have a chat window on my page (is a widget) that when it´s open on a Mobile it should use the 100% of the height of the screen ON ANY DEVICE.

The problem is when I use the dev chrome tool works fine, but when I use a mobile phone it doesn´t because on the mobile I have top and bottom toolbars depending on the phone that I don´t have on the dev tool, and on Android depending on the Brand of the Phone is has differents layouts too.

What I have is simple, i have a div that wraps all the content of the chat and I have this class on it:

```
.msg-container-base {
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    clear: both;
}
```

the 80px above are because the chat has a top heading and a bottom input text that each has 40px.

Is there anyway to resolve this using only CSS?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the height of the screen from CSS.

This is how you can calculate the height of the `div` you are using. Just run a `console.log` after it with the value you set. If this is what you are asking. (Note: this is javascript)

```
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
```

Or:

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
```

`clientHeight` includes padding.

`offsetHeight` includes padding, scrollBar and borders. (Note `offsetheight` doesnt work in I.E. 10 or below)

Further you could use `@media`. With this you can decide as when the CSS you write is fired, if you say `min-width: 600px;` for example, it will fire all CSS written in it above the 600px width, `max-width` on the other hand decides when the fired CSS should stop when the screen size gets too large. (Note: this is for css) https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Hope this helps you out any further, cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I went with a similar solution, instead of clientHeight or offsetHeight I used window.innerHeight and set that value to the <div> that has the class 'msg-container-base'. I did this in a function that I call on the eventListener orientationchange

Comment: @Santiago I am glad I was able to help to get to your solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

To make your container fit to screen use the following style:

```
html,body {height:100%}
.you-container {height:100%}
```